# Too much space in footmisc paragraph mode

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

 % Footnotes on the same line
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\begin{document}
\footnote{Loremip: Dolorsi}.
\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit consec: {https://www.gelitsedd.mod/ddaemporinci/}}
\end{document}
```

The footnotes appear with a lot of space between words (I think in an effort to justify the text) which looks really ugly. Is there a way to change the alignment of text in the footnotes when it is in paragraph mode?
I tried passing `ragged` as an option to `footmisc` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can patch in `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e`  to get

[image]

or the default `\raggedright` (allows more raggedness so stretches word spaces less) to get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

 % Footnotes on the same line
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\makefootnoteparagraph{\par}{\RaggedRight\par}{}{}
\begin{document}
\footnote{Loremip: Dolorsi}.
\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit consec: {https://www.gelitsedd.mod/ddaemporinci/}}
\end{document}
```